# Oracle Cursor Incorrect Declaration when Parsing to Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a homework assignment that I am close on, but keep getting an error.

I have a table for Restaurants that was created as such:

```
create table Restaurant(rID int, name varchar2(100), address varchar2(100), cuisine varchar2(100));
```

The values were populated as such:

```
insert into Restaurant values(101, 'India House Restaurant', '59 W Grand Ave, Chicago, IL, 60654', 'Indian');
insert into Restaurant values(102, 'Bombay Wraps', '122 N Wells St, Chicago, IL, 60606', 'Indian');
insert into Restaurant values(103, 'Rangoli', '2421 W North Ave, Chicago, IL, 60647', 'Indian');
insert into Restaurant values(104, 'Cumin', '1414 N Milwaukee Ave, Chicago, IL, 60622', 'Indian');
insert into Restaurant values(105, 'Shanghai Inn', '4723 N Damen Ave, Chicago, IL, 60625', 'Chinese');
insert into Restaurant values(106, 'MingHin Cuisine', '333 E Benton Pl, Chicago, IL, 60601', 'Chinese');
insert into Restaurant values(107, 'Shanghai Terrace', '108 E Superior St, Chicago, IL, 60611', 'Chinese');
insert into Restaurant values(108, 'Jade Court', 6'26 S Racine Ave, Chicago, IL, 60607', 'Chinese');
```

I need to Create a table called Restaurant_Locations, which i did via:

```
CREATE TABLE Restaurant_Locations (
rID Int,
name varchar2 (100),
street_address varchar2(100),
city varchar2(100),
State varchar2(100),
Zip int,
cuisine varchar2(100)
);
```

With this, I need to write a cursor using SQL and PL/SQL in Oracle to process each row from the Restaurant Table, extraction info to populate the Restaurant_locations table, and parse the address into Street_address, city, state, and zipcode fields.

Here is what I have for the cursor so far:

```
DECLARE
 A Restaurant.RID%TYPE;
 B Restaurant.Name%TYPE;
 C Restaurant.street_address%TYPE;
 D Restaurant.City%TYPE;
 E Restaurant.State%TYPE;
 F Restaurant.Zip%TYPE;
 G Restaurant.cuisine%TYPE;
 
CURSOR R1Cursor IS
    select rId,
        name,
        regexp_substr(address,'[0-9]{1,} [A-Z]{1,} [A-Z][a-z]{1,} [A-Z][a-z]{1,}') as street_Adrress,
       regexp_substr(address,'\w+',1,5) as City,
       regexp_substr(address,'\w+',1,6) as State,
       regexp_substr(address,'\w+',1,7) as Zip,
       cuisine
   from Restaurant;
    
BEGIN
OPEN R1Cursor;
LOOP
    FETCH R1Cursor INTO A, B, C, D, E. F, G;
    
    IF R1Cursor%FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Found restaurant' || B);
    END IF;
    
    EXIT WHEN R1Cursor%NOTFOUND;
    
    INSERT INTO Restaurant_Locations (rID, name, street_address, city, state, Zip, cuisine) VALUES (A, B, C, D, E, F, G);
    
END LOOP;
CLOSE R1Cursor;
END;
```

I believe I have declared my variables properly, and even tried defining the columns and corresponding values in the INSERT INTO statement explicitly, however, I'm still getting this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 15:
PLS-00302: component 'STREET_ADDRESS' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 4, column 4:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 5, column 15:
PLS-00302: component 'CITY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 4:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 15:
PLS-00302: component 'STATE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 4:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 7, column 15:
PLS-00302: component 'ZIP' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 7, column 4:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 23, column 31:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 23, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 31, column 116:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 31, column 116:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "F": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 31, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Looking for guidance on why my declarations are incorrect?

Comment: Single letter variable names should be avoided, they make your code hard to follow. Reread the error messages, pay attention to the line numbers - the first error is that you’ve declared C as having the same data type as restaurant.street_address, restaurant doesn’t have this column.

Comment: Briefly, you're confused among `Restaurant` and `Restaurant_Locations` tables within the variable declaration.

Comment: You don't need a cursor for this.  And using a cursor when you don't need one is a really bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Correct cursor code with proper declarations and change to multi-letter variables:

```
DECLARE
 a_rid Restaurant_locations.RID%TYPE;
 a_name Restaurant_locations.Name%TYPE;
 a_street_address Restaurant_locations.street_address%TYPE;
 a_city Restaurant_locations.City%TYPE;
 a_state Restaurant_locations.State%TYPE;
 a_zip Restaurant_locations.Zip%TYPE;
 a_cuisine Restaurant_locations.cuisine%TYPE;
 
CURSOR R1Cursor IS
    select rId,
        name,
        regexp_substr(address,'[0-9]{1,} [A-Z]{1,} [A-Z][a-z]{1,} [A-Z][a-z]{1,}') as street_Adrress,
       regexp_substr(address,'\w+',1,5) as City,
       regexp_substr(address,'\w+',1,6) as State,
       regexp_substr(address,'\w+',1,7) as Zip,
       cuisine
   from Restaurant;
    
BEGIN
OPEN R1Cursor;
LOOP
    FETCH R1Cursor INTO a_rid, a_name, a_street_address, a_city, a_state, a_zip, a_cuisine;
    
    IF R1Cursor%FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Found restaurant' || a_name);
    END IF;
    
    EXIT WHEN R1Cursor%NOTFOUND;
    
    INSERT INTO Restaurant_Locations (rID, name, street_address, city, state, Zip, cuisine) VALUES (a_rid, a_name, a_street_address, a_city, a_state, a_zip, a_cuisine);
    
END LOOP;
CLOSE R1Cursor;
END;
```